# Protect struct-pointer from getting garbage collected when passed to an unmanaged dll

Tags: visual-c++, garbage-collection, dllimport, unmanaged

Dummy-code to illustrate:

foo.h

```
[...]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential)]
public value struct Bar
{
    int in;
    string str;
};

Foo(String^ string); 

private:
    Bar *bar;
```

foo.cpp

```
[...]
[DllImport("dummy")]
int _stdcall Baz(Bar *bar, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)]String ^str);

Foo::Foo(String ^str)
{
    bar = new Bar;
    if (bar != nullptr)
    {
        if (!Baz(bar, str))
        {
            delete bar;
            bar= nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs sporadically, what happens is that bar is null when Baz gets called, which I assume is due to it getting garbage collected while the code that runs inside the dll is excecuted.

So far I've tried reading up on pin_ptr etc, but I can't find any good resources on how to use it, and when I try to declare the member variable to be a pin_ptr-type, I get an error saying that it can't be a class member.

I'm quite lost, if anyone can tell me how to fix it, why it needs fixing and how the fix works, that'd be great.

edit:
Further info; Baz is only one of many imported dll-methods used, almost every one of the uses the same parameters though, meaning that the first on is Bar *bar, followed by other parameters which are passed into the wrapper function.

Comment: This cannot go anywhere, you are wildly guessing at the declarations and you are getting them very wrong.  Contact the owner of the DLL and ask for the .h file, the .lib file so you can link and both a debug and release build of the DLL.  The VS version he uses is very important, it must match yours.

Comment: The owner of the dll is not in business anymore, the code provided is part of a wrapper written in visual c++ by the owner, I am trying to fix it.

It works most of the time, it's just that bar seems to get garbage collected and therefore throws a nullref, something that's happening in my application, which should imply that it's locally fixeable, and doesn't need any support from the creator of the dll.

Correct me if I'm  wrong, I have very limited knowledge of interoperability.

Comment: IIRC `new` operator doesn't create instances that get garbage collected, `ref new` or `gcnew` do.